# How much data does recv() return from a socket after blocking?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, network-protocols, tcpsocket

If I call `recv(1024)` on a connected, blocking, TCP socket, and there is no data in the receive buffer, the `recv` call blocks, waiting for data to arrive into the receive buffer.

I've read in several places that `recv` blocks until ***"some"*** data is in the buffer. How much is "some"? Is there a threshold? And is there a timeout if that threshold is not met (and more than zero bytes are available)?

If my application needs to receive 100 bytes and the first `recv` call blocks, what's stopping `recv` from returning one byte at a time as it arrives in the receive buffer in my application receive loop for the full 100 bytes?

Comment: `some` is one character or more.

Comment: The only thing that can stop `recv()` from returning one byte at a time is the `MSG_WAITALL` flag. And if the sender sends one byte at a time at long enough intervals, not even that. More usually you will get unwanted coalescing rather than unwanted splitting, but your application code has to be able to cope with both.